# Why use CoreText render text layout, text can show in 1px width path?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-text

I wrote a code use CoreText layout some texts like picture below. Red rectangle is text area, black rectangle is empty for images or other objects. I use `kCTFrameClippingPathsAttributeName` tell CoreText that, black rectangle will not show texts.

[image: core text text layout]

Detail picture as below:

[image]

**Why some text rend at this position? Red rectangle and black rectangle only have a very small area, size only 1px width, why text come out?**

Right red rectangle frame is `(533, 40, 440, 668)`, right small rectangle frame is `(534, 98, 440, 399)`.

code like that:

```
CGPathRef textArea; 

// An array of clipping paths
NSMutableArray * clippingPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
for (TNPageMedium *medium in self.media) {
    NSDictionary *clippingPathDict = @{(NSString *)kCTFramePathClippingPathAttributeName:(__bridge id)path};
    [clippingPaths addObject:clippingPathDict];
}

NSDictionary  *optionsDict = @{(NSString*)kCTFrameClippingPathsAttributeName : clippingPaths};

// create frame using texAreaPath, an optionDictionary contains clipping paths
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(pos, 0), textAreaPath, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(optionsDict));

// Draw Frame
CTFrameDraw(frame, context);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `attributedString` is missing paragraph style information.

I guess you created `NSAttributedString` from `NSString`, and didn't provide `kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName` key-value in attributes dictionary.

Comment: Should all of the CTParagraphStyleSpecifiers be used in CTParagraphStyleSetting?